Wagmi experimental 'useWriteContracts' return data
I am really confused with the returned data from this hook. In the docs is stated that the returned data is the 'Most recent block number seen.'
const {
    writeContractsAsync,
    isPending,
    isSuccess,
    data
  } = useWriteContracts();

const handleSendTokens = async () => {
    const tx = await writeContractsAsync({
      contracts: [
        {
          abi: abi,
          address: address,
          functionName: 'transfer',
          args: ['0xAddress', ethers.parseUnits(inputAmount, 18)]
        }
      ],
      capabilities: { ...capabilities }
    });
  };

example response: 0x507097c0e9670e7c0b763003c14ae78f29a3234214345a789591fb44d82409a40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002105
How can I approach this, can I extract tx data from it?

Can you share the body of the transfer() function that you're calling? Is it an ERC20 transfer?

Yes, it is an ERC20 transfer, it's working with normal calls from ethers.Js or the non experimental wagmi hooks like useWriteContract. I forgot to say that the actual tx is successful when i am using this experimental hook, but this response is bugging me...

Okay, and what exactly are you logging when you’re getting this response?

In the response the data property from the experimental hook

Okay, that seems to be the abi-encoded input params that you're passing in the  transfer() function. Have you passed 0xc14aE78f29A3234214345a789591FB44D82409A4 and 8453 as args?

What do you want to extract?
